# Error With MessageBox C++

Tags: c++, messagebox

I am working on my code in c++ but when I enter the code for a messagebox to display

```
MessageBox::Show(NMessage1);
```

All I get are the errors
"'MessageBoxA' : is not a class or namespace name"
and
"'Show' : identifier not found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageBox::Show` is not a windows API, it just `MessageBox` or `::MesssageBox` and you will need to `#include <windows.h>` .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to use the .NET `MessageBox::Show` in `C++/CLI`

Do you have this in your code

```
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
```

If not, add it, that's where MessageBox::Show is defined.

If you already have it, then your problem may be because you also include `windows.h`.

`windows.h` `#define`s `MessageBox` to `MessageBoxA` in non UNICODE builds. Hence you aren't able to use `MessageBox` from `System.Windows.Forms`. `undef`ing the `MessageBox` macro will fix your problem.

Do the following

```
#undef MessageBox
```

after the place where you `#include <windows.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you name your class MessageBox?  That's also a Windows API function (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  When you build with Unicode I think there a `#define` that makes that MessageBoxA.

If you just want to call the Windows API refer to the link.  If this is your class use a different name.